# Laravel 5.6 how to populate select in modal window

Tags: laravel-5

I am having problems to populate a select on a modal window with data retrieved from database, I would like to know if there's a shorter bullet-proof way to do it using Jquery.

[select in modal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftbsW.jpg)

Index.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ url('beneficios/create') }}" class="btn btn-primary mb-3"    
role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalbeneficio" 
id="crear-beneficio">Crear Beneficio</a
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you are you using bootstrap for creating modals, right?

Comment: yes, i am using bootstrap 4 like in the example updated above

Answer (score 0):

Just put somewhere in your `index.blade.php` the code for your modal, as described in [bootstrap official docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/):

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalbeneficio">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Insert here whatever HTML you need to be displayed inside the modal --!>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but  how do you populate a dropdown as in the image from the database?